# Foreach loop duplicating a taxonomy thumbnail image

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I'm using the [Taxonomy Images](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/taxonomy-images/) plugin to output thumbnails next to my tax terms.

I'm using `get_term_children` in a foreach loop to pull out the terms, and a sub-foreach loop to pull out the thumbnail images.

Things are working fine, except the images get printed twice. I must be doing something wrong with one/both of the loops.

Anyone see any obvious foreach issues?

```
<?php
$termID = 10;
$taxonomyName = "tool";
$termchildren = get_term_children( $termID, $taxonomyName );
$termThumbs = apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-get-terms', '', array('taxonomy'=> 'tool'));

echo '<ul>';
foreach ($termchildren as $child) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomyName );
    echo '<li>';
    echo wp_get_attachment_image( $termThumb->image_id, 'thumb' )   ;

        if ( ! empty( $termThumbs ) ) {
        foreach(  $termThumbs as $termThumb ) {
            print wp_get_attachment_image( $termThumb->image_id, 'thumb' )  ;
        }
    }

    echo '<a href="' . get_term_link( $term->name, $taxonomyName ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
    echo '</li>';

}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

The screenshot: http://cl.ly/1y2q2J0S0m3x0e0T0N1D

Comment: You're echoing the image first and then printing it in another loop. Why?

Answer (score 2):

**1).** Inside your `foreach` (term child) loop you first have:

```
echo wp_get_attachment_image( $termThumb->image_id, 'thumb' )   ;
```

but `$termThumb` isn't set yet. So on the first iteration it doesn't do anything.

**2)** Then you have another `foreach` loop:

```
if ( ! empty( $termThumbs ) ) {
    foreach(  $termThumbs as $termThumb ) {
        print wp_get_attachment_image( $termThumb->image_id, 'thumb' )  ;
    }
}
```

where `$termThumbs` is (presumably) an array of term-thumbnail objects. So you print every term thumbnail image.

Then on the next iteration of the `foreach` (i.e. the for the next term child) `$termThumb` is now set to the last object in the `$termThumbs` array. And so in **(1)** the term is now set, and so prints the thumbnail for that object, before doing **(2)** again displaying all thumbnails again.

Comment: So, I need to set $termThumb outside the foreach, and then just echo it inside?  This doesn't work: https://gist.github.com/2585777 but should be close?

Comment: Get rid of the inner `foreach` and find a way of get `$termThumb->image_id` from the current `$term` object. But I wouldn't know how you'd do that because I'm not familiar with Michael's plug-in - it's probably in the plug-ins documentation.